# Create Jar with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, resources

My project in eclipse approximately shows the following folders:

```
application
- src
- JRE System Library [1.6]
- API.wsdl
```

In my project, I would like to use File > Export... > Executable JAR

Well that works fine, with some exception: If I want to run my application.jar, I still need to copy the file API.wsdl in the same location as application.jar.

I don't get it, because the file API.wsdl is ALREADY included in my application.jar:

```
application.jar
- com
- META-INF
-.classpath
-.project
- API.wsdl
```

Hope someone can help me, how to avoid the copying of API.wsdl in the same location as application.jar.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I can solve the problem, but normally this is because you need to access the wsdl file as a resource via the class loadeer...

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the problem :) I have to access the wsdl file as a resource via the class loader! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to access the files - here the wsdl file - via your `ClassLoader`. This way the file will be fetched from the jar, rather than from the file system.